# update an element in deeply nested array after checking multiple conditions in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Say, I have a document structure

```
[ {
  "name" : "in",
  "states" : [ {"name" : "up", 
                "cities" : [ {"name" : "dp", "places" : [ {"name" : "pvr"}, {"name" : "lpu"} ] }, 
                            {"name" : "mo", "places" : [ {"name" : "pvr"}, {"name" : "lpu"} ] } ]}, 
               {"name" : "tn", 
               "cities" : [ {"name" : "ab", "places" : [ {"name" : "pvr"}, {"name" : "lpu"} ] }, 
                            {"name" : "cd", "places" : [ {"name" : "pvr"}, {"name" : "lpu"} ] } ]} 
             ]
  },
  {
  "name" : "ik",
  "states" : [ {"name" : "up", 
                "cities" : [ {"name" : "dp", "places" : [ {"name" : "pvr"}, {"name" : "ont"} ] }, 
                            {"name" : "lo", "places" : [ {"name" : "zcv"}, {"name" : "bft"} ] } ]}, 
               {"name" : "kl", 
               "cities" : [ {"name" : "hp", "places" : [ {"name" : "bgh"}, {"name" : "vhi"} ] }, 
                            {"name" : "mp", "places" : [ {"name" : "hup"}, {"name" : "plm"} ] } ]} 
             ]
} ]
```

I would like to change the `"{"name" : "pvr"}"` to `"{"name" : "cvr"}"` of "`places`" where `("name":"ik" and "states.name":"up" and "cities.name":"dp")`. How to check for all three conditions and update?

Answer (score 1):

Since the position of array element you want to update is unknown, you will need to fetch the matching states and cities, iterate over places and the set the new value in your application code. Alternatively, you can model your data differently if this kind of update is done frequently so you do not have so many levels deep of array elements.